# Why is this value returning zero?

Tags: java, physics, game-physics

I have a method inside of a ball class that has location, velocity, and acceleration attributes. I'm trying to create a rudimentary version of collision detection, which involves calculating the distance between the two balls. I have the following code for my distance:

```
public float getDistance(Ball ball2)
{
    float distance = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ball2.x - x, 2) +
                                Math.pow(ball2.y - y, 2)));
    return distance;
}
```

In another part of the code I print the value of this distance repeatedly, and I keep getting zeros. Why is that?

EDIT: I figured it out. I forgot that the coordinates of the position were being stored in a vector object, so instead of saying ball2.x I should have said ball2.position.x. Now everything is calculating correctly and my program is working. Thanks for the help folks! I'm not sure if this questions should be closed or whatever, but whatever the mods think is most appropriate!

Comment: What are the values of each of the variables just before that line?

Comment: What is the value of ball2.x and x  same for y

Comment: You need to provide the input parameters you passed in and also `x` and `y`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Chances are that the inputs are not what you think they are, or you are not printing out what you think you are.

Comment: Seperate the code out and print out what the console says at each step.   My bet is that if you do something like `sqrt(2)` will return an int, because it is an int in the args.   Cast it to a float first.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Your bet is not correct: `Math.sqrt()` returns a `double`.

Comment: Yea, i totally messed that one up there.   lol

Comment: The inputs come from the x and y coordinates of the locations of the balls within a container object. I've just tested and confirmed that the x and y coordinates for both of the balls are normal floats. I don't think that the coordinates are the problem.

Comment: So @Euclid'sCompass the value of ball2.x  is equal to x and same for y ?

Comment: No, I screwed up. I forgot that the coordinates of the balls were being stored in a vector object, so instead of saying ball2.x I should have said ball2.position.x and instead of just x I should have said this.position.x. Sorry for the mixup!!

Comment: sidenote: Math.pow(x, 2) is sloooower than x*x, since it is designed to allow things like Math.pow(2.5, -0.2314)... source: http://dhruba.name/2012/09/01/performance-pattern-multiplication-is-20x-faster-than-math-pow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is fine. The problem lies elsewhere.

It could be that `ball2.x == this.x` and `ball2.y == this.y`. This could be because `ball2` and `this` are the same object, or because you forget to initialize `x` and `y`, or for a variety of other possible reasons.

Another possibility is that the value you're printing out is not the result of calling `distance()`, but is something else (for example, because of an error in the code).

Comment: No, I screwed up. I forgot that the coordinates of the balls were being stored in a vector object, so instead of saying ball2.x I should have said ball2.position.x and instead of just x I should have said this.position.x. Sorry for the mixup!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to compare the distance to the second ball?

```
  public float getDistance(Ball ball2, Ball ball1)
{
    float distance = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ball2.x - ball1.x, 2) +
               Math.pow(ball2.y - ball1.y, 2)));
    return distance;

}
```

You are currently subtracting x from x, returning 0.

Comment: I assume getDistance is a method of ball, so it doesnt need to pass the second ball.

Comment: Well then x and y aren't defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

Because ball2.x = x  and ball2.y = y

Answer (score 0):

If your ball2.x and x are both integers, then when they are within 1 unit of each other, x - x can round to 0 because you are still doing integer math. You should cast them as floats before you subtract them. then do the math.

This goes the same for ball2.y and y.

Comment: I am sorry, but the first sentence makes no sense. There is absolutely no way the subtraction operator can round the result.

Comment: ugh, you're right. I was thinking of divide. nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

As some people already commented there is nothing wrong with your code. I copied and paste it in a demo class and got 0.223

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        Ball b1 = d.new Ball(0.1f, 0.5f);
        Ball b2 = d.new Ball(0.2f, 0.7f);
        System.out.println(b1.getDistance(b2));
    }

    class Ball{
        float x,y;

        public Ball(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public float getDistance(Ball ball2)
        {
            float distance = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ball2.x - x, 2) +
                                        Math.pow(ball2.y - y, 2)));
            return distance;
        }
    }
}
```